# Setting text on multiple UILabels in a NSArray collection

Tags: xcode

I am trying to set multiple labels with identical text and cannot for the life of me figure out the proper way of doing so.

I am using an ibaction to handle a switch that will either change several labels in a collection to say "yes" or "no" and have been trying both a for loop and makeobjectsperformselector withobject method, but so far no luck.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? From the question it seems that just a line of code per `UILabel` is all that would be necessary, why is that not a solution? SHow the coce that is not working.

Comment: Are you using an `IBOutletCollection`? If so, did you make sure it is connected and has items?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tag of UILabel subviews to help you out with this. If it's not already set, go to the storyboard, click on your label, go to the Attributes Inspector and under "View" there's a tag field.

If the labels all have different tags (0,1,2...) , the following loop should do what you need:

```
for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews] ) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

         UILabel *currentLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:subview.tag];
         currentLabel.text = @"yes";            
    }
}
```